# Windows 10 Update: Couldn't Connect to Update Service

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates

```
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 20H2
System Type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
OS Build: 19042.804
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0
```

I have been unable to update my Windows 10 installation for quite some time using `Settings: Updates -> Security -> Windows Update`.

```
Error Encountered:
Last Checked: Today, 6:24 AM
We couldn't connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now. If it still doesn't work, make sure you're connected to the Internet.
```

I had Windows 10 version 1903 ever since that came out. Thankfully, I was able to update using the in place update to 20H2 yesterday after downloading the ISO file. I tried the update service again to no avail, same problem.

I ran the Windows 10 Troubleshooter, both from `Settings` and from `Control Panel`. There was no error found:

```
Windows Update Publisher details

Potential issues that were checked
Some security settings are missing or have been changed: Issue not present
Check for missing or corrupt files: Issue not present
Service registration is missing or corrupt: Issue not present
Check for Windows Update issues
    Detects issues related to Windows Update. Issue not present  

Potential issues that were checked Detection details 
 Some security settings are missing or have been changed Issue not present  
 Check for missing or corrupt files Issue not present  
 Service registration is missing or corrupt Issue not present  
 Check for Windows Update issues Issue not present  
Detects issues related to Windows Update. 
Detection details Expand 
InformationalIsPostback_RC_PendingUpdates 
IsPostback: False 
InformationalService Status 
Problem with BITS service : The requested service has already been started. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182. System.Management.Automation.RemoteException  
 
Collection information 
Computer Name:  JMR-ENG-SARAH 
Windows Version: 10.0 
Architecture: x64 
Time: Tuesday, March 2, 2021 7:34:33 AM 

Publisher details Expand 

Background Intelligent Transfer Service 
Find and fix problems that may prevent background downloads from working 
Package Version: 3.5 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Network Diagnostics 
Detects problems with network connectivity. 
Package Version: 4.0 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Update 
Resolve problems that prevent you from updating Windows. 
Package Version: 9.3 
Publisher: Microsoft Windows 
Windows Update 
Resolve problems that prevent you from updating Windows. 
Package Version: 9.2 
Publisher: Microsoft Corporation
```

I ran the [Windows 10 Reset](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/how-toreset-windows-update-components-in-windows/14b86efd-1420-4916-9832-829125b1e8a3) restarting the computer afterwards to no avail.

As to one suggestion to do an update, I successfully did an update from `1903` to `20H2` to no avail.

I would like to get the `Windows Update` working again.

Thoughts?

Comment: It should be pointed out that currently you are running the last update released.  [KB4601382](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-24-2021-kb4601382-os-builds-19041-844-and-19042-844-preview-1a7ed2b4-017d-2644-a1e8-dd6bf14cba76) while released is a Preview update.  Depending on your Windows Update settings not being offered that update is normal.  If you manually download KB4601382 from the Windows Update Catalog website are you able to install it?  I am going to guess this machine is NOT connected to an AD domain and/or internal WSUS?

Comment: @Ramhound My machine is in a domain. There are many Windows 10, both Pro and Enterprise, here and all of them are able to run Windows Update successfully. On a working computer, WU just says no more updates, if none exist. My PC did the same thing up until about 2-years ago or so, when WU stopped working. I got tired of 1903, so I was able to manually update. Now, I would like to get WU working, about time.

Comment: Did you try the DISM / SFC sequence of commands?

Comment: @John I tried the `DISM / SFC` sequence to no avail, exact same problem. I just did not comment as I did not do #2, the repair install, yet, though I successfully upgraded from 1903 to 20H2 yesterday with no issues. I even finally got the new Edge Chromiam browser.

Comment: Try the Repair Install as the Repair with Keep Everything fixes about 3/4 of problems. It might be worth your while to temporarily disjoin the domain, repair and rejoin.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran the Windows 10 Reset restarting the computer afterwards to no
> avail.

The reset referred to above is resetting the Window Update components. This and other steps referred to in the question have not worked.

**Try first:**  DISM and SFC

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. (2) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup (3) DISM.exe /Online
> /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth (4) SFC /SCANNOW (5) Restart when all
> the above is complete and test.

**Then second** (if DISM does not work), do a Windows 10 Repair Install:

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  **There are 3 ways to
> proceed**, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.